# How to modify an existing BLECentral class into a singleton class?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I'm trying to make the BLE Central class into a Singleton class?
I'm running into a few crashes while trying to implement it.
Here is my code:

```
//This is the BLE Central Class
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


var txCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
var rxCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
var blePeripheral : CBPeripheral?
var characteristicASCIIValue = NSString()



class BLECentralViewController : UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    //Data
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var RSSIs = [NSNumber]()
    var data = NSMutableData()
    var writeData: String = ""
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    var characteristicValue = [CBUUID: NSData]()
    var timer = Timer()
    var characteristics = [String : CBCharacteristic]()

    //UI
    @IBOutlet weak var baseTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func refreshAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        disconnectFromDevice()
        self.peripherals = []
        self.RSSIs = []
        self.baseTableView.reloadData()
        startScan()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.baseTableView.delegate = self
        self.baseTableView.dataSource = self
        self.baseTableView.reloadData()

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Disconnect", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        disconnectFromDevice()
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        refreshScanView()
        print("View Cleared")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        print("Stop Scanning")
        centralManager?.stopScan()
    }

    /*Okay, now that we have our CBCentalManager up and running, it's time to start searching for devices. You can do this by calling the "scanForPeripherals" method.*/

    func startScan() {
        peripherals = []
        print("Now Scanning...")
        self.timer.invalidate()
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLEService_UUID] , options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:false])
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 17, target: self, selector: #selector(self.cancelScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    /*We also need to stop scanning at some point so we'll also create a function that calls "stopScan"*/
    func cancelScan() {
        self.centralManager?.stopScan()
        print("Scan Stopped")
        print("Number of Peripherals Found: \(peripherals.count)")
    }

    func refreshScanView() {
        baseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    //-Terminate all Peripheral Connection
    /*
     Call this when things either go wrong, or you're done with the connection.
     This cancels any subscriptions if there are any, or straight disconnects if not.
     (didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic will cancel the connection if a subscription is involved)
     */
    func disconnectFromDevice () {
        if blePeripheral != nil {
            // We have a connection to the device but we are not subscribed to the Transfer Characteristic for some reason.
            // Therefore, we will just disconnect from the peripheral
            centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(blePeripheral!)
        }
    }


    func restoreCentralManager() {
        //Restores Central Manager delegate if something went wrong
        centralManager?.delegate = self
    }


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        blePeripheral = peripheral
        self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
        self.RSSIs.append(RSSI)
        peripheral.delegate = self
        self.baseTableView.reloadData()
        if blePeripheral == nil {
            print("Found new pheripheral devices with services")
            print("Peripheral name: \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
            print("**********************************")
            print ("Advertisement Data : \(advertisementData)")
        }
    }

    //Peripheral Connections: Connecting, Connected, Disconnected

    //-Connection
    func connectToDevice () {
        centralManager?.connect(blePeripheral!, options: nil)
    }


    //-Connected
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("*****************************")
        print("Connection complete")
        print("Peripheral info: \(String(describing: blePeripheral))")

        //Stop Scan- We don't need to scan once we've connected to a peripheral. We got what we came for.
        centralManager?.stopScan()
        print("Scan Stopped")

        //Erase data that we might have
        data.length = 0

        //Discovery callback
        peripheral.delegate = self
        //Only look for services that matches transmit uuid
        peripheral.discoverServices([BLEService_UUID])


        //Once connected, move to new view controller to manager incoming and outgoing data
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController

        firstVC.peripheral = peripheral

        navigationController?.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
    }



    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to connect to peripheral")
            return
        }
    }

    func disconnectAllConnection() {
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(blePeripheral!)
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let services = peripheral.services else {
            return
        }
        //We need to discover the all characteristic
        for service in services {

            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            // bleService = service
        }
        print("Discovered Services: \(services)")
    }



    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            return
        }

        print("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics!")

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            //looks for the right characteristic

            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(BLE_Characteristic_uuid_Rx)  {
                rxCharacteristic = characteristic

                //Once found, subscribe to the this particular characteristic...
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: rxCharacteristic!)
                // We can return after calling CBPeripheral.setNotifyValue because CBPeripheralDelegate's
                // didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic method will be called automatically
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Rx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(BLE_Characteristic_uuid_Tx){
                txCharacteristic = characteristic
                print("Tx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic)
        }
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if characteristic == rxCharacteristic {
            if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
                print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)

            }
        }
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if error != nil {
            print("\(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        if ((characteristic.descriptors) != nil) {

            for x in characteristic.descriptors!{
                let descript = x as CBDescriptor!
                print("function name: DidDiscoverDescriptorForChar \(String(describing: descript?.description))")
                print("Rx Value \(String(describing: rxCharacteristic?.value))")
                print("Tx Value \(String(describing: txCharacteristic?.value))")
            }
        }
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error changing notification state:\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

        } else {
            print("Characteristic's value subscribed")
        }

        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
            print ("Subscribed. Notification has begun for: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Disconnected")
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Message sent")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Succeeded!")
    }

    //Table View Functions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.peripherals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlueCell") as! PeripheralTableViewCell
        let peripheral = self.peripherals[indexPath.row]
        let RSSI = self.RSSIs[indexPath.row]


        if peripheral.name == nil {
            cell.peripheralLabel.text = "nil"
        } else {
            cell.peripheralLabel.text = peripheral.name
        }
        cell.rssiLabel.text = "RSSI: \(RSSI)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        blePeripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]
        connectToDevice()
    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
            // We will just handle it the easy way here: if Bluetooth is on, proceed...start scan!
            print("Bluetooth Enabled")
            startScan()

        } else {
            //If Bluetooth is off, display a UI alert message saying "Bluetooth is not enable" and "Make sure that your bluetooth is turned on"
            print("Bluetooth Disabled- Make sure your Bluetooth is turned on")

            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth is not enabled", message: "Make sure that your bluetooth is turned on", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            alertVC.addAction(action)
            self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions are:**

- How can I modify the `BLECentral` class to use as a singleton so I
  can call from any view controller class to read and write data?
- Can I simply make the first view controller as a singleton instead of the BLE central and read/write by calling this from other view controller class?
- Or can I extend the first view controller class scope by using
  extension?
- I'm currently able to read/write data but peripheral doesn't seem to
  be called properly sometimes, therefore gets disconnected? Any
  suggestions/fixes?

Here is my `FirstViewController` class:

```
     class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPeripheralManagerDelegate {

        var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?
        var peripheral: CBPeripheral!

        viewDidLoad(){

        //I'm calling the blePeripheral from BLE class to the peripheral in the current class
        peripheral = blePeripheral

        }

        //I have a button here to send some data and only when I receive the data I want to go to the next view controller

        @IBAction func login(_sender: AnyObject) {
        //This is my write code

        let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x1A, 0x2B, 0x3C, 0x4D ]
                let Transmitdata = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
                peripheral.writeValue(Transmitdata as Data, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
                print("Data Sent",Transmitdata)

        //Give time for data to be received fromdevice
        sleep(1)


        //let ReceiveData = rxCharacteristic?.value
                if let ReceiveData = ReceiveData {
                    let ReceivedNoOfBytes = ReceiveData.count
                    var ReceivedByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
                    (ReceiveData as NSData).getBytes(&ReceivedByteArray, length: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
                    print("Data Received ",ReceivedByteArray)


        //checking if we received the right data?
        if(ReceivedByteArray[0] == 10 && ReceivedByteArray[1] == 20 && ReceivedByteArray[2] == 30 && ReceivedByteArray[3] == 40){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Second_View", sender: self)
        }
        }

    }
```

And the `SecondViewController` class:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController{

var firstview: FirstViewController?


var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?
var peripheral: CBPeripheral!

override func viewWillAppear(_animated: Bool){
let peripheral = firstview?.peripheral
let peripheralManager = firstview?.peripheralManager
}



//I have another button here to direct me to third view controller class

@IBAction func mainmenu(_sender: AnyObject){


//send some bytes

//receiver some bytes 

//similar to the first view controller

If correct data is received
{
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Main_M", sender: self)
}
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
if segue.destination is Main_M
{
let gotoM = segue.destination as? Main_M
gotoM?.peripheral = firstview?.peripheral
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477776/ble-peripheral-disconnects-when-navigating-to-different-viewcontroller/47481780#47481780

Comment: @LeoDabus Hi Leo, Thanks for your response but I have already tried creating a class like that but not sure what centralManager/peripheral code related to the connected ble that I should put in it? Can you pls guide me how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @Cevat Mert D Thanks for the edit, I am still new to the forum so will keep the question structure in mind from next time :)

Comment: It is just a reference for you to have an idea of how to declare and access the properties that you need to share the same instance in multiple view controllers

Comment: First recommendation I would say is to drop the whole singleton pattern, it's always painful to use and makes things much harder to test in the future, I would say the safest way to do that is to either

a-Declare the class in your AppDelegate, then use all views to get their reference from that 

or 

b- initiate the class in the first view then pass it around as a parameter to all other views.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg Thanks for your response Mr Berg. Yes after a bit of reading I have come to the same conclusion as Singletons are hard if I had to completely disconnect. Appreciate your time here. Hopefully you could show me a bit more about the steps in our sample git repo.