# How to read ble peripheral value correctly in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to read a byte array from my one view controller to another, please find my code below.

From my First View

```
class First: UIViewController {

var myByteArray = [UInt8](repeating:0, count: 20)

viewDidLoad(){
......}
```

Few statements later hers where I read my data in a function

```
func passThis(){

let ReceiveData = rxCharacteristic?.value
        if let ReceiveData = ReceiveData {
            let ReceivedNoOfBytes = ReceiveData.count
            myByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
            (ReceiveData as NSData).getBytes(&myByteArray, length: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
            print("Data Received ",myByteArray)
               }
```

This is my Second View that I'm trying to read my array from First View

```
class Second: UIViewController {

var myByteArray2 = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 20)

viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
let fvc = First()
myByteArray2 = fvc.myByteArray

print(myByteArray2)
}
```

Now I have [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] from myByteArray
but have [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] from myByteArray2 ?

Can somebody help?

Also how do I clear the readValue buffer in rxCharacterstic before writing and reading new values?

Any help/comments appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT -> How my passing is done

From BLECentral

```
class BLECentral: ...

var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

//After Scanning and connecting

func centralManager(_central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral){

peripheral.delegate = self

peripheral.discoverServices([BLEUUID])



//Once connected, move to new view controller to manager incoming and outgoing data
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! First

        firstVC.peripheral = peripheral

        navigationController?.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Now in my First under prepare for segue block I'm passing the peripheral like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 if segue.destination is Second
{
let vc2 = segue.destination as? Second
vc2.periperal = blePeripheral
}
}
```

Comment: How are you transitioning view controllers? Is First calling Second?

Comment: @Diesel Hi Diesel, Many thanks I was able to solve it with a little reading from your answer :)

Comment: No problem. What you are doing is correct! I recommend going through the Apple tutorial (just read it) as it will save you hours and cover the basics. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ is a good place to start or their free books if you have more time on the Book Store called "App Development with Swift."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `First` view controller from your `Second` view controller, instead of accessing the one already created.

```
//Create a new View Controller
let fvc = First()
```

So you have two `First` that are made now. What you want to do is access the already created `First` view controller. Assuming there is no other way, you want to have a "Singleton". This is a very bad way to handle this, as I'll explain later, and there is most likely a better way, but I'm going to give a solution to access First from Second if they never communicate, but First is already created.

If you declare in `First` a piece of code like:

```
static let shared = First()
```

Then that singleton can be accessed via

```
let first = First.shared
```

That being said, that's a really bad way of handling communication between view controllers. If you call Second from First, you should pass the data from First to Second (or you could pass a reference of First to Second so Second can access First).

There is generally good ways to pass data between view controllers in the

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

method before you navigate. Whenever, whatever, makes the Second view controller should pass it the data it needs.

Lastly, another reason the Singleton view controller is a terrible idea is that it gets away from the MVC concept. So if you can't pass the proper data to Second, you probably need a new class that handles the data for you that both First and Second can work with which is the Model in MVC.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824265/how-to-modify-an-existing-blecentral-class-into-a-singleton-class  This is exactly what I have , so can you help me now on how it needs to be done? I don't want it as singleton, I can read and write in one view controller and I just want the same functionality passed to my other views? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please check my edit on how I pass the peripheral. Many Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. Realize, if you have lots of data, you may create a whole new class that handles that data. For example, I have an app with multiple food places in it. My class goes out and downloads places, stores them, and has functions like getPlace or getAllPlaces or refreshPlaces. It is a singleton as well, so everyone has access to the places. That way I don't have to download the data each time I need it. Here is a pretty good read on MVC: https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach