# Am I creating two singleton objects or just a reference?

Tags: swift, singleton

When creating a singleton object of a UIView inside the view class, I use the static keyword.

```
class AView: UIView {

static let shared = AView()

}
```

Now in my UIViewController class, instead of using "AView.shared" to access that singleton object, I create a constant reference inside the View Controller.

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {

let singleton = AView.shared

// now I use singleton.whatever to access the view properties and methods.

}
```

Question 1:
Am I creating a second object by creating "let singleton = AView.shared"? I am NOT trying to create a second object because that's redundant and I'm sure could lead to memory leaks somehow, right? The goal is for me to just create a reference inside that ViewController class for readability.

Question 2:
Is this good convention?

Comment: No. `shared` is a static property on the class. They all refer to the same object. I prefer using `AView.shared`

Comment: @LeoDabus ok thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47481780/2303865